# Kepler + V31, keeps doing "populating components in your workspace" for 10 mins

Tags: force.com, eclipse

Ever since I updated to Kepler and V31 of the plug in, I have run into bizarre issues. The first one was the project created in Helios wouldn't push updates to the cloud. I deleted the project and pulled it down again. I set the Work Online mode and that solved the problem.

But now every time I make a small change as merging things in or updating a class or object description etc from within Eclipse, it is taking an enormous amount of time for it to push and build the project.

1) It shows "populating components in your workspace" for about 10 mins
2) It then proceeds to build workspace which is taking another 10 mins.

Not sure if I am missing a setting or something but it seems its doing double work or something as in push changes and then pull the entire project down or something. Any thoughts or anyone else face similar issue? Has anybody resolved the issue?

Thanks
Praful

Comment: I don't see this problem listed here https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues so suggest you add it.

Comment: Have you tried mavensmate?  The eclipse stuff drove me to a better place

Comment: @ShaneMcLaughlin I have been thinking about it a lot but wasn't sure how much support is built in for Force.com. I am using Aside.io a lot of lately.

Comment: mavensmate is the force.com api/plugin for sublime text.  Works pretty great!

Comment: I am having the same problem with Kepler and v 31.0 of the API.  I reverted to 29.0 and the problem disappeared.